# Php: Detect if user included the javascript-snippet or not, on their website

Tags: php, javascript

I got a simple javascript-file, wich my users need to include on their website for example. I want to detech if the snippet is include or not. The way I'm going to detect it, is by using a unique key in the js-file, for anyone who needs to know.

Been searching a lot for this, but haven't come up with any results yet.

Comment: Could you please clarify for what purpose you're checking? It's hard to answer without knowing exactly what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about the response from the server but only want to detect the script loading on the server side, sending a small amount of data to the server, you can load a URL using the browser's image preloading feature:

```
new Image().src = "http://your.server.name/track.php?time=" +
    new Date().getTime() + "&uniqueKey=" + uniquekey;
```

`new Date().getTime()` ensures that the requested URL is unique, bypassing the web browser's cache.

Answer (score 0):

You could have the JavaScript file make an Ajax call to announce its presence.